# Changing Title via Alert Controller

Tags: xcode, uinavigationbar, uialertcontroller

I want to be able to change the title displayed in the `navigationBar`. I have the `alertController` setup and it appears fine, however after inputting the newTitle text, the current title disappears but the new title doesn't appear. I have tried reloading data in the `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, as well as in the button press event itself (as shown in code). Any input is appreciated.

```
    @IBAction func changeTitleBarButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        let titleChange = UIAlertController(
            title: "Change Title",
            message: "Please input text to change the title",
            preferredStyle: .alert)

        titleChange.addTextField { (textField) in
            textField.placeholder = "Input new title"
        }

        titleChange.addAction(UIAlertAction(
            title: "Cancel",
            style: .cancel,
            handler: { (cancelAction) in
                titleChange.dismiss(animated: true)
        }))

        titleChange.addAction(UIAlertAction(
            title: "Change Title",
            style: .default,
            handler: { (changeAction) in
                let newTitle = self.textField?.text
                titleChange.dismiss(animated: true)
                self.navigationItem.title = newTitle
                self.imagesTableView.reloadData()
        }))

        self.present(titleChange, animated: true)

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem is you read the `text` value from unrelated `textField` (And its probably `nil` or `empty`). You may want to use the first `textField` of the alert instead of `self.textField?.text`:

```
titleChange.addAction(UIAlertAction(
    title: "Change Title",
    style: .default,
    handler: { (changeAction) in
        let newTitle = titleChange.textFields![0].text // instead of `self.textField?.text`
        titleChange.dismiss(animated: true) // this line is not required. You can get rid of it freely.
        self.navigationItem.title = newTitle
}))
```

<sub>Make sure you are no setting the `navigationItem.title` elsewhere (like `viewWillAppear` or etc.)</sub>